# Track Errors in UI

Tags: errors, analytics

I was thinking about tracking the errors a user encounters within the UI. The idea is that if I'm notified of such errors, I can start to see trends and correct major issues. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: it will depend on your definition of **UI errors**, but for a wide range of definitions you may have for this, the answer is yes, it has been made many times before. It would be handy if you can provide an example of what do you mean exactly

Comment: Some businesses track their customer-service calls to see where problems are in their site. I don't think that's what you're talking about, though.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest point in your claim is what is error in UI.

There are two sides in interaction. You can check **technical errors** with manual or automated testing. Also there are browsers, and servers, and network, which could be the cause of technical errors. You can track technical errors, as you know the right metrics and their ranges, so the anomalies can be detected.

**Human side** is harder. You can see a mouse tracking on the picture below. The user haven't pressed big-yellow-call-to-action button for some reason. Is it error?

[image]

The cause of a human's "wrong" behavior are:

- wrong mental model
- slip
- bad visual or interaction design
- wrong user
- wrong context or environment
- wrong user's goal
- ...

You can minimize and fix some of these factors significantly by doing Cognitive Walkthrough and Heuristic Evaluation, and Usability Test.

But this doesn't mean, you need no to track users' behavior. The tools like Google Analytics can give quantitative insights of something goes wrong in term of your goals. Then qualitative research methods help you to fix it. Until the next round.